# Difference in order of start and join for multiple threads?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am developing an android app that uses threads. Can you please tell me the difference between these 3 pieces of code?

First:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (new Class1(param1));
Thread t2 = new Thread (new Class2(param2));

t1.start();
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Second:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (new Class1(param1));
Thread t2 = new Thread (new Class2(param2));

t1.start();
t1.join(); 

t2.start();
t2.join();
```

Third:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread (new Class1(param1));
t1.start();

Thread t2 = new Thread (new Class2(param2));
t2.start();

t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Also, how would it be different if both classes (`class1` and `class2`) extend the same class `Class`?

I still need to know if both classes Class1 and Class2 extend the same class (MAINCLASS) and implement runnable, would a conflict happen? in other words can it work?
Thank you.

Comment: The t1.join() method simply makes your current thread wait for the t1 thread to end before proceeding with the next instruction.

Comment: If both classes extend the same class and implement runnable, could the conflict among functons happen?

Comment: Functions don't conflict in them selves. The conflict only arises if the work on the same data. So you must consider the variables and fields the methods are working on. If the instances of those variables (the data) is shared you must consider if potential conflicts can arise. If they alway work on different instances there won't be any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) and 3) are similar: they both start 2 threads and wait for them to finish.

2) will wait for t1 to finish before starting t2 making it somewhat pointless using threads in this example

Comment: If they both extend the same class where class 1 uses functions from main class other than the functions used by class2, could that create a conflict?